# Showing a GitHub project page only under custom subdomain, never via folder path

Tags: github, github-pages

I have an organization GitHub Pages repository set up, and it's served through a custom domain name (let's say, http://example.com/).

I also have a couple of projects pages which I want to be accessible via a subdomain only (let's say, http://project.example.com/), but it turns out that they will also be accessible at a different URL (that is, http://example.com/projectname/).

Is there any way to avoid this? Both the organization pages and the project pages have CNAME entries set up, and the DNS records seem to be correctly configured.

Comment: What technical resources are available to you?  Just DNS? How about a Web server?

Comment: I can only tweak the DNS entries and the GitHub CNAME entries, and GitHub Pages is more than enough for serving the site contents. The problem is, actually, it's serving it "too much". :) (that is, the same exact content is reachable via two different URLs)

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: Webhosting and/or GitHub account related questions are off-topic

Comment: @dpassage Because it's redundant, and I would like to be able to choose my website structure.

Answer (score 3):

> http://project.example.com/ will also be accessible at http://example.com/projectname/
>
> > **Is there any way to avoid this?**

I was able to avoid this via a [project pages](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages) setup for each *subdomain* as well as the *domain*. It didn't work with CNAME records so I had to use A records in the server side configuration. Every record would point to the Github IPs **192.30.252.153** and **192.30.252.154**, using the `subdomain` as host or `@` for the `domain.com` part.

[image: Example]

For future users looking into [how to map a Github page](https://help.github.com/articles/about-custom-domains-for-github-pages-sites/) to a domain / subdomain:

1. [Create new](https://github.com/new) Github repo and add a `gh-pages` branch.
2. Add your `index.html` and a CNAME file with only one line `sub.domain.tld`.

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bucaran/294b9b8839ebdf5343f2) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I am aware of is hiding `http://domain.tld/projectname/` content with a robots.txt file on the web server that serves that domain.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

Comment: As I understand, that would instruct crawlers and make that part of the website unlisted from search engines, but it would still be accessible from humans, am I wrong?

Comment: You are correct. I am not sure how else you could proceed however.