# stop github project page subpath redirecting to custom subdomain

Tags: redirect, github, dns, github-pages

I have a GitHub pages set up with a custom domain.
I have some project pages which I would like to be available at *project.domain.com*, **in addition** to being available at *domain.com/project*.
Setting up the project repository with a CNAME file, and adding a CNAME record to the dns will make *project.domain.com* work, but redirects *domain.com/project* to *project.domain.com*.
Is there a way to have both URLs serve the same project page, without either redirecting to the other?
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913321/showing-a-github-project-page-only-under-custom-subdomain-never-via-folder-path) question asks the opposite, how to automatically redirect from a subpath to a subdomain, but both options (A records or CNAME records) don't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have both.

You project repository is served as a folder of :

- `username.github.io` -> `username.github.io/projectname`
- or `domain.com` -> `domain.com/project`, if you add a `CNAME` for `domain.com` in `username.github.io`

If you add a CNAME in a project repository, an automatic redirection is applied in accordance with this CNAME content. In your case `project.domain.com`.